# Pandas delete all duplicate rows in one column if values in another column is higher than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe where there are duplicate values in column A that have different values in column B.

I want to delete rows if one of column A duplicated values has values higher than 15 in column B.

Original Datafram

| A Column | B Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |

Desired dataframe

| A Column | B Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
dfnew = df.groupby('A Column').filter(lambda x: x['B Column'].max()<=15 )
dfnew.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
dfnew = dfnew[['A Column','B Column']] 
print(dfnew)
```

output:

```
   A Column  B Column
0         1        10
1         1        14
2         3         5
3         3        10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `groupby()` and `transform()`

```
df.loc[~df['B Column'].gt(15).groupby(df['A Column']).transform('any')]
```